# Woocommerce Square Payment Plugin issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, square

Our client is facing issue while trying to do payment via Woocommerce Square Payment Plugin. As according to their website reference, they currently only supports Real time payment, no sandbox like structure. Please see this link:- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-square/

> WooCommerce Square does not currently have a sandbox mode for testing
>   purposes. A regular product can be purchased to test the payment
>   gateway (minimum amount is $1)

I am new to wordpress and didn't find the way to test the Square plugin and don't know how to troubleshoot this issue. I even didn't find any help by google search. Found some users asked the same question with no reply on them. According to Square Credit card Payment error, there may be miss in some required parameter or invalid field value type like we can see from error "Invalid Enum value" for country. But client has already saved his all account details, as i can see from admin panel from his profile (billing and shipping address).
Unanswered question.
https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/11725925/comments?page=16

Could any one please help? Find screenshot for more details.

[image]

Comment: The error shows that it needs a valid country enum (currently being passed blank it looks like). I'm not familiar with Woocommerce Square plugin itself, but it definitely needs a valid country enum. If the account details looks correct, I would suggest reaching out to Woocommerce support to see if they could help.